# JPA Query org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have `@OneToOne` bi-directional relationship between following tables:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class StudentAccount implements DomainModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idstudentaccount;
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idstudent")
    private Student student;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    //getters and setters
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements DomainModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idStudent;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=StudentAccount.class)
    private StudentAccount studentAccount;
    //getters and setters
```

How to write the query to get if the username exists in the database?
This is what i have tried:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public boolean usernameAvailability(String username, Integer studentId) {

    Query checkUsername = getEntityManager()
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StudentAccount s WHERE s.username=:usernameParam AND s.idstudent<>:accIdParam");
    checkUsername.setParameter("usernameParam", username);
    checkUsername.setParameter("accIdParam", studentId);
    long count = (long) checkUsername.getSingleResult();
    if (count > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: idstudent of: com.af.domain.StudentAccount
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be `s.student.idstudent<>:accIdParam`

Remember that `s` refer to `StudentAccount` with a nested `student` property, with a further nested `idStudent` property

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and it's not working. The exception is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Student of: com.iquest.af.domain.StudentAccount [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM com.af.domain.StudentAccount s WHERE s.username=:usernameParam AND s.Student.idStudent<>:accIdParam]
 org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)`

Comment: it's `student` with lowercase `s`, not  `Student`. It's the property and not class name: `s.student.idStudent`

Comment: I am trying to update the Student (edit profile) and now i get the following error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'UK_tr1t4oo8ivgiur0xy63odvvfy'`. Do you have any idea what can cause this exception? Because i do not have duplicate entries into the database.

Comment: That's a different question really, where you'll have to show the code for the update operation